# Add locations to users in firebase with react native and expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I want to simulate the location of all users from database. The users are saved in fireabse realtime databse, with all their signup informations. I want to display the location of the users on the map, and their status after i simulate their location. My project is in react native expo (blank template).
I tried to add the locations with this function, based on the users id, but it doesn't work.
After that, i wanted to fetch the user's location on the map.

Code bellow:

```
const addLocationToUser = async (userId, latitude, longitude, status) => {
  try {
    const location = await getLocation();
    const { latitude, longitude } = location;

    const userRef = ref(database, `users/${userId}`);
    const locationRef = ref(userRef, "location");

    // Set the location data for the specific user in the Realtime Database
    set(locationRef, {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      status: status,
    });

    console.log("Location added to user in the Realtime Database");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error adding location to user:", error);
  }
}

addLocationToUser(
  "ZUtHxSRqdXYNHi6agBsRxzRJPkr2",
  46.763968,
  23.563625,
  "busy"
);
addLocationToUser(
  "fsMEOtNdaUcSv5toQEjfXA8ueYF2",
  49.763968,
  25.563625,
  "free"
);
addLocationToUser(
  "lX04kCQY68SxcJhHoxocGuYBeLi2",
  46.758798,
  23.551193,
  "free"
)

const fetchLocations = async () => {
  const locationsRef = collection(database, "locations");
  onSnapshot(locationsRef, (snapshot) => {
    const locationsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    setUserLocations(locationsData);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchLocations();
}, []);
```

Comment: You are defining  `latitude`, `longitude` as arguments for `addLocationToUser` extract them from `getLocation`.